# Building in Android Studio, the gradle won't build due to duplicate classes

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies

I have worked through all my build errors, when trying to build the project it fails due to the following errors.

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10)
```

and

```
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
```

I have attempted to exclude specific classes within certain libraries like so.

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0") {
        exclude module: 'kotlin-stdlib'
}
```

Comment: Can you add your complete build.gradles to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `jar` task:

```
duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
```